# undefined local variable or method `object' for error_messages.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the ruby on rails tutorial. And I received a error on my signup page only.

```
undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007feb442f6a98>:0x007feb442f8438>
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <% if object.errors.any? %>
2:  <div id="error_explanation">
3:      <h2>
4:          <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
```

Here's my error_messages file.

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved:
            </h2>
            <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
            <ul>
            <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <% end %>
```

Now here's my users/new.html file.

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object passed down with `:object =>` becomes a local variable in the partial with the same name as the partial. So in this case, where your partial is called `error_messages`, the first line should be

```
<% if error_messages.errors.any %>
```

Now obviously this looks a little confusing - which is perhaps a suggestion the naming of the partial is wrong.

Also, partial view files should be named starting with an underscore - `shared/_error_messages` - to mark they're not full views; they should be rendered with `render :partial => 'shared/error_messages'`; and the `:object` local variable doesn't carry the underscore.

See [some docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer) on rendering partials.

Comment: The solution did not work. I have the file named _error_messages.html.erb already. When I changed to your solution this is what I received:


undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

1: <% if error_messages.errors.any %>
2:  <div id="error_explanation">
3:   <h2>
4:    <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>

Comment: Are you sure that `@user` gets a value in the controller? (and in that case it's more correct to use `:user`in the `form_for...`)

Comment: You still have `object` at line 4. You need to change _each_ instance of `object` in your partial to `error_messages`.

Comment: The problem is this line <%= render 'fields', :f => f %> from new.html.erb. As when I remove it the page works fine.

Comment: Oh, you're not passing `f` correctly. Try `<%= render :partial => 'fields', :locals => {:f => f} %>`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to post your `fields` partial.

Comment: Did not work. Here's my _fields.html.erb file https://gist.github.com/pwz2k/4731235

Comment: Your very first line is rendering `error_messages` again, but without an object. Since you've _just_ rendered it, you probably want to drop that line.

Comment: Removing it from the _fields.html file worked! Thanks for all the help